# DataGridView is not painted properly

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` in a wizard which is created using `TabControl`. When this `DataGridView` is shown, a mixture of cell contents and previous wizard page is displayed. When I click next to show next wizard page and then go to previous page, `DataGridView` display correctly. I take a picture of this:

[image]

First cell from right in first row corrupted.
How can I fix this?

**EDIT:**
You can reproduce this bug this way: place a small DGV in a form. My DGV width is 268 and its height is 247. Add six columns to it. Put these lines of code in form load event method:

```
string[] row = new string[6];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    row[0] = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    row[1] = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    row[2] = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    row[3] = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    row[4] = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    row[5] = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Finally go to DGV properties then DefaultCellStyle and change BackColor to Transparent. Run and the only thing you need to do is to scroll to right. A picture of this problem:

[image]

I think the problem is Transparent color. Changing Transparent to some color other than Transparent will solve the problem but I do not know why.

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing how your painting works. Perhaps, share some code.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that's "corrupt" or a painting issue. Perhaps that cell just has the wrong `Font`.

Comment: @Ginosaji I changed all fonts but same problem happened.

Comment: @Neolisk I add columns and then rows. Nothing special. What do you want to know?

Comment: Ideally give us a [reduced test case](http://css-tricks.com/reduced-test-cases/).

Comment: I just noticed the little boxed 3 in the corrupt version. I've used the `DataGridView` within a `TabControl` without any issues like this. Are you doing any custom painting at all in this application?

Comment: @Ginosaji This '3' is from a text box in previous tab and must not be there! There problem is parts of previous tab like that '3' remains and combines with DGV. Seems a problem in painting DGV. I do not use any custom painting.

Comment: @Neolisk I'll try to reproduce this with minimum code so that you can test it.

Comment: A temporary workaround may be to handle the `TabControl.SelectedIndexChanged` event, calling `.Refresh()` on the affected `DataGridView`s. Without the code I couldn't even begin to guess what caused the problem to begin with.

Comment: I edited question so that you can reproduce the bug.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you .. yes this is related to Transparent colour , i have changed Transparent to White and my DGV works well.